# In R Shiny, how to move user inputs from sidebar panel into a modal dialogue box?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

In the below MWE code, the user inputs values into a matrix in the sidebar panel of the "Liabilities Module" tab. Works fine. But I'd like to move the matrix input grid *from* the sidebar panel and *into* a modal dialog box. How would that be done?

That matrix input grid would no longer appear in the sidebar panel. Instead it would only appear in the modal dialog box.

The model outputs in the main panel (linked to the first matrix row labeled "A") would continue to be linked to the relocated matrix input grid.

You'll see towards the bottom of the MWE below a skeleton of my attempt to create a modal dialog, in `observeEvent(input$showLiabilityGrid...`

At the very bottom I also include an image explaining what I'm trying to do.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

button2 <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,style="width:90px;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:80%")}

matrix1Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

pct <- function(x){paste(format(round(x*100,digits=1),nsmall=1),"%",sep="")} # convert to percentage

vectorBase <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorPlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w,main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z,type="b",col="blue",pch=19,cex=1.25)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
                        style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
    # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
      uiOutput("Panels") 
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("By balances", value=2),
        tabPanel("By accounts", value=3), 
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   button2('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                   button2('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 ), # close fluid row
                 
                 div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),
                 
                 # Shows outputs on each page of main panel   
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  base_input  <- reactive(input$base_input)
  showResults <- reactiveValues()

  yield   <- function(){vectorBase(60,input$base_input[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  # --- Conditional panels rendered here rather than in UI to eliminate invocation flashing ------------>
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4",
        
        actionButton('showLiabilityGrid','Input Liabilities',style='width:100%;background-color:LightGrey'),
        setShadow(id='showLiabilityGrid'),
        div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
        
        matrix1Input("base_input"),
        div(style = "margin-top: 0px"), 
        useShinyjs(),
      ), # close conditional panel
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  # --- Below produces vector values as default view when first invoking App --------------------------->
  vectorsAll <- reactive({cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(yield()[,2]))}) # Produces vector values
  output$table1 <- renderTable({vectorsAll()})
  
  # --- Below produces vector values after clicking "Vector Values" button; see above for pre-click ---->
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,
               {showResults$showme <-
                 tagList(tableOutput("table1"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  # --- Below produces vector plots -------------------------------------------------------------------->   
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorPlot(yield(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  # --- Below sends both vector plots and vector values to UI section above ---------------------------->
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})

  # --- Below for modal dialog inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------>
  
  observeEvent(input$showLiabilityGrid,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 # ???
               ) # close modalDialog
               ) # close showModal
               } # close showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you may only need to make the move in UI, your server may not need to change. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging and with help from YBS in another Stack Overflow post, the below complete MWE now works and resolves the original query. The user inputs into a modal dialog box, with results showing in the main panel. The user interface is much cleaner using a modal dialog in this manner.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

button2 <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,style="width:90px;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:80%")}

matrix1Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
              cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

pct <- function(x){paste(format(round(x*100,digits=1),nsmall=1),"%",sep="")} # convert to percentage

vectorBase <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorPlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w,main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z,type="b",col="blue",pch=19,cex=1.25)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
                        style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
      # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
      uiOutput("Panels") 
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("By balances", value=2),
        tabPanel("By accounts", value=3), 
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   button2('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                   button2('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 ), # close fluid row
                 
                 div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),
                 
                 # Shows outputs on each page of main panel   
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  base_input  <- reactive(input$base_input)
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  
  yield   <- function(){vectorBase(60,input$base_input[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  # --- Conditional panels rendered here rather than in UI to eliminate invocation flashing ------------>
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4",
        actionButton('showLiabilityGrid','Input Liabilities',style='width:100%;background-color:LightGrey'),
        setShadow(id='showLiabilityGrid'),
        div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
      ), # close conditional panel
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  # --- Below produces vector values ---------------------------------------------------------------------->
  
  # Below now defines the vectorsAll object before user clicks on actionButton "Input Liabilities".
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$showLiabilityGrid)){df <- NULL}
    else {
      if(input$showLiabilityGrid < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(0.2))}  # define what you want to display by default
      else {
        req(input$base_input)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(yield()[,2]))
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({vectorsAll()})
  
  # --- Below produces vector values after clicking "Vector Values" button; see above for pre-click ---->
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,
               {showResults$showme <-
                 tagList(tableOutput("table1"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # --- Below produces vector plots -------------------------------------------------------------------->   
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorPlot(yield(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  # --- Below sends both vector plots and vector values to UI section above ---------------------------->
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
  # --- Below for modal dialog inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------>
  observeEvent(input$showLiabilityGrid,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 matrix1Input("base_input"),
                 div(style = "margin-top: 0px"),
                 useShinyjs(),
               ) # close modalDialog
               ) # close showModal
               } # close showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what position you would like the input module in. However, this does move it and it works.

I had to add a library, other than that I've commented out the code I would have removed from your original code.

Because the sidebar was now blank it's a `navbarPage()`

You will see a new `fluidrow()` in your `tabPanel('Liabilities module'...`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)  # added for the function setShadow

button2 <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,style="width:90px;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:80%")}

matrix1Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

pct <- function(x){paste(format(round(x*100,digits=1),nsmall=1),"%",sep="")} # convert to percentage

vectorBase <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorPlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w,main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z,type="b",col="blue",pch=19,cex=1.25)}

ui <- 
 # pageWithSidebar(
  navbarPage(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    # sidebarPanel(
    #   fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
    #                     style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
    #   # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
    #   uiOutput("Panels") 
    # ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("By balances", value=2),
        tabPanel("By accounts", value=3), 
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value = 4,
  # added - taken from sidebar coding
                 fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
                                   style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
                 # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
                 uiOutput("Panels"),
  # end add
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   button2('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                   button2('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 ), # close fluid row

                 div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),

                 # Shows outputs on each page of main panel
                 uiOutput('showResults')),
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
 ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  base_input  <- reactive(input$base_input)
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  
  yield   <- function(){vectorBase(60,input$base_input[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  # --- Conditional panels rendered here rather than in UI to eliminate invocation flashing ------------>
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4",
        
        actionButton('showLiabilityGrid','Input Liabilities',
                     style='width:100%;background-color:LightGrey'),
        setShadow(id='showLiabilityGrid'),
        div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
        
        matrix1Input("base_input"),
        div(style = "margin-top: 0px"), 
        useShinyjs(),
      ), # close conditional panel
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  # --- Below produces vector values as default view when first invoking App --------------------------->
  vectorsAll <- reactive({cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(yield()[,2]))}) # Produces vector values
  output$table1 <- renderTable({vectorsAll()})
  
  # --- Below produces vector values after clicking "Vector Values" button; see above for pre-click ---->
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,
               {showResults$showme <-
                 tagList(tableOutput("table1"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # --- Below produces vector plots -------------------------------------------------------------------->   
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorPlot(yield(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  # --- Below sends both vector plots and vector values to UI section above ---------------------------->
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
  # --- Below for modal dialog inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------>
  
  observeEvent(input$showLiabilityGrid,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 # ???
               ) # close modalDialog
               ) # close showModal
               } # close showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Shiny App]